# How to return a byte[] to C# in C++ CLR

Tags: c#, c++-cli

I'm using C++ CLR to wrap a native C++ dll. So that the C++ CLR dll can be accessed by a C# project.

The problem is that when I want to return a byte[] to C#, and write such code in CLR:

```
static System::Byte[]^ GetTestByteBuffer()
{
    System::Byte[]^ byte = gcnew System::Byte[128];
    return byte;
}
```

but it cannot pass compilation. Anyone can help me?

compilation error:

```
error C3409: empty attribute block is not allowed 
error C3409: empty attribute block is not allowed error C2146: syntax error "^": 
error C2334: unexpected token(s) preceding '{'; skipping apparent function
```

Comment: "cannot pass compilation" - I don't suppose you could give us some kind of idea what the compilation error is?

Comment: Thanks for your reply! Here is the compilation error:             error C3409: empty attribute block is not allowed    error C3409: empty attribute block is not allowed   error C2146: syntax error "^": error C2334: unexpected token(s) preceding '{'; skipping apparent function

Answer (score 31, accepted):

This is the way you declare a byte array in C++/CLI:

```
array<System::Byte>^
```

Google is your friend...